# Yii, custom filter is not working

Tags: yii, filter

My custom filter isn't working. Can anyone please correct me?

In my

```
public function actionAdmin($mid=null) {
    // the appropriate codes here... 

    $date = ">= ".date("Y-m-d");

    $this->render('admin', array(
        'model' => $model,
        'mid' => $mid,
        'date'=>$date,
    ));
}
```

In my admin.php, I added this line in the appropriate field, in this case, `dateEnd`.

**UPDATED**

```
array(
        'name'=>'dateEnd',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'150px'),
        'filter'=>array('0'=>'', '1'=>$date),
),
```

Okay, so here's the problem. No matter what I click on, it's not filtering anything. I want it to filter either a blank space OR a date of today.

Can I please know what have I done wrong? Please feel free to correct me. Thanks!

Comment: Where is the `'filter'=>array('0'=>'', '1'=>$date)`? I think you have problem in cgridview, right? Can you provide your cgridview code?

Comment: There, already added it in. They're different CGridViews BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line :

```
'filter'=>array('0'=>'', '1'=>$date),
```

To this line:

```
'filter' => array(">= ".date("Y-m-d") => Yii::t('app', 'Still On Leave')),
```

Basically the first parameter is the real value, where as the second part is the View to be displayed.

In the First line, `'1'=>$date` means 1 value but to display a `$date` field on the CGridView's filter. It will take the value 1 to filter instead of the `$date` field.

Treat it like the `Select` element in HTML, where you have this line:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

Javascript basically takes the value instead of the word `One` being displayed.

This is the same explanation for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access passed variable **inside cgridview**. For this purpose, you can define a global variable inside your controller, and access it inside cgridview, something like this:

```
class Yourcontroller extends Controller {

    public $date;
    public function actionAdmin($mid=null) {
      // the appropriate codes here... 

      $this->date = ">= ".date("Y-m-d");

      $this->render('admin', array(
        'model' => $model,
        'mid' => $mid
      ));
   }
}
```

Now, you can access `date` inside grid:

```
array(
    'name'=>'dateEnd',
    'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'150px'),
    'filter'=>array('0'=>'', '1'=>$this->date),
 ),
```